# difference in sup and inf of $f(x)$ is less than $L_1$ norm

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following true for a  function $f(x)$ defined over a compact set $X$?

$\sup f(x) - \inf f(x) \leq \int |f(x)| dx$

Do we need the function to be continuous?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true, not even for continuous $f$.  Consider $f(x)=x^n$ for $x\in K=[0,1]$.  The integral is $1/(n+1)$ but $\sup_K -\inf _K = 1-0=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to relate this difference to any norm other than L-infinity?

Comment: Not really,  unless you impose smoothness conditions on $f$.  For instance, $\|f\|=|f(0)|+\int_{[0,1]} |f'(x)|\,dx$ gives a bound of the sort you seem to want, but only for a much-restricted set of functions.